# How to set margin or padding for DrawableLeft Icon in android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to set padding and margin for Edittext border to place the icon on drawable Left, but am not able to achieve as expected.

Please help

Below is my xml Code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/EtMobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_below="@id/pleaseLogin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_oval_shape"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_login_mobile"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:hint="Mobile number"
            android:inputType="text"/>
```

Actually I want like this:

[image: Login_screen]

My result is:

[image: custom_login_screen]

Comment: whats your ic_login_mobile image size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing as a `DrawableLeft`, I suggest you to take an `ImageView` ... So that you can have more control on the image.

You can have many functionalies with ImageView, but in EditText you cannot.

Lastly, place them both in RelativeLayout.

Hopefully it will work as expected.

Comment: thanks!! @UmangBurman i have tried using Relative Layout!!

Answer (score 0):

just put padding inside your btn_oval_shape.xml. Put inside your shape code:

```
<padding
android:bottom="3dp"
android:top="3dp"
android:left="3dp"
android:right="3dp"/>
```

Comment: sample code plz.. @TryingToBeSmart